# Can't vertical align the content of 2 divs inside div with height auto

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to vertical align the content of 2 divs inside another div with height auto. The 2 divs inside are using bootstrap columns. What I really want is to align the text in the paragraph from the first div/column to the center of the height of the second div/column.

```
<div class="project-row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block col-xs-6">
            <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos qui blanditis praesentium voluptatum deleniti</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-monitor" ng-src="assets/img/teamsight-monitor.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "vertically align"...the `divs` **are** aligned...did you mean the content? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Wvmeab

Comment: Yes I want to align the text from the first div so it's at the middle. The second div has an image with a height of around 500px. So the text should sit around half of the size depending on how much text there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex box like this:

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="project-row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block col-xs-6">
            <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos qui blanditis praesentium voluptatum deleniti</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-monitor" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great it works. Are there any severe browser incompatibility issues by using this?

Comment: I'm glad to help you, check this out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ in the section of **Browser Support** to see the compatibility.

Comment: Oke I'll read it up later. Many thanks!